# Extract specific string from array with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

String example

```
[{"identifier" : "value1"},{"identifier" : "value2"}]
```

Desired output

```
value1,value2
```

I will be using powershell for this, have gone though the string and its methods but can't put my finger on how. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have provided more information in order to get a better answer. To solve your problem, you could *deserialize* the JSON(or load the file first) using the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet, select the `identifier` property and finally `-join` the result:

```
('[{"identifier" : "value1"},{"identifier" : "value2"}]' | ConvertFrom-Json).identifier -join ','
```

Then you get your desired output:

```
value1,value2
```